# Command output print side by side

Tags: command-line, shell, bash-scripting

Following is my command output:

```
# ls -la | grep -i text | awk '{print $9}' 
text1.txt
text2.txt
text3.txt
text4.txt
```

I wanted to print output value as:

```
text1.txt:text2.txt:text3.txt:text4.txt
```

Comment: [don't parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425). And instead of piping `ls` to `grep` it's better, shorter and faster to use globbing: `ls *text*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Mohammad Alzatari Ans helped me to resolve this issue.

```
$ ls -la | grep -i text | awk '{printf ":%s", $9}'|awk '{print substr($1,2);}'

text1.txt:text2.txt:text3.txt:text4.txt
```

Problem Solved

Comment: Instead of posting a new answer, upvote/mark the answer which helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Goodness no, [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You want

```
( files=(*text*); IFS=:; echo "${files[*]}" )
```

I use a subshell so the IFS variable in your current shell is not affected.

If you are certain your filenames do not contain newline characters, you can do

```
ls -1 *text* | paste -sd:
```

Answer (score 1):

You could throw things into a bash script like so:

```
unset list
for file in `ls -a | grep -i 'text'`; do list=$list"$file:"; done
echo ${list::-1}
```

The initial `unset` is to remove previous values if you're running the command multiple times. To get rid of the final colon (:), you can do that while you `echo` if you're running bash `4.2` or higher, like I have in my code.

Answer (score 1):

please try this, it should work

```
$ ls -la | grep -i text | awk '{printf ": %s", $9}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact solution and need some inprovement.

Just pipe the output to **`tr`**

```
$ ls -la | grep -i text | awk '{print $9}' | tr '\n' ':'

text1:text2:text4:text5:
```

I couldn't remove the last `:` at end and also could not make it to next line.

Comment: `paste` is useful here in place of `tr`